# What steps should a person take to heal one's body after pulling an all-nighter?

Tags: sleep, lifestyle, recovery

Regardless of cause (crying baby, hospital emergency, procrastination, insomnia), what steps should be taken to return to their original sleep?

Maybe they should try to sleep as soon as possible or get exercise to help sleep earlier the next night? Or maybe there are things people should eat or avoid eating?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer too, and would prefer short naps of about half an hour over sleeping early next night :-)

Comment: @ABcDexter I heard (from a serious sleep expert, who was rather old and performed lots of research for many years) that 90 minute segments are most useful, meaning that a 5.25 hr sleep may not be a lot better than a 4.5 hr sleep but a 4.5 hr sleep may be much better than a 3.75 hr sleep.  Sleep/rest/nap wasn't very significant, as long as you give the body appropriate time and let the body decide whether you fall unconscious or not.  I can personally attest that trying for segments of 90 minutes has seemed to minimize undesirable tiredness effects, so I guess it seems he was right.